# Send form data across domain IE issue

Tags: php, forms, internet-explorer

I have an app in PHP that works fine with his own login form. But I want to allow users to authenticate from a web site with another form in another domain. The form is equal than the original, same fields, same names.

The problem is that it works in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't works in IE.

When I submit the form, I got no data on `$_POST` var. I display it with `var_dump` or `print_r` and both shows an empty array.

I already disabled `XSS filter` on IE Secury options but none.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, have you considered implementing OpenID-based authentication between the sites instead?  Having one site submit a POST form to another is blocked in some browsers for security reasons (believe it or not, IE is actually doing something good here); trying to work around this is not something I would advise, especially since it grows more and more likely that future browser versions of the major browsers will prevent this from occurring so as to prevent form hijacking, phishing, and other nastiness that can harm the end user.

Comment: The point is that is not an web site, is a particular organizational system. If this method I'm trying doesn't work as you said because of these security prevents, I will have to use another method.